# Dagger 2. Не могу разобраться в чем ошибка!

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger2, dagger

Всем привет! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с ошибкой Dagger 2. Вот то, что выдают мне логи. Я к сожалению новичок и не могу самостоятельно разобраться с проблемой.

```
D:\Projects\AndroidStudioProjects\clean-architecture-android-materials\OsterrigLampLED\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\astar\osterriglampled\di\component\RepositoryComponent.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    public abstract AppRepository getRepository();
                    ^
  symbol:   class AppRepository
  location: interface RepositoryComponentD:\Projects\AndroidStudioProjects\clean-architecture-android-materials\OsterrigLampLED\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\astar\osterriglampled\di\module\RepositoryModule.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    public final AppRepository providesRepository$app_debug(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                 ^
  symbol:   class AppRepository
  location: class RepositoryModuleD:\Projects\AndroidStudioProjects\clean-architecture-android-materials\OsterrigLampLED\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\astar\osterriglampled\di\module\ViewModelModule.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    AppRepository repository) {
    ^
  symbol:   class AppRepository
  location: class ViewModelModuleD:\Projects\AndroidStudioProjects\clean-architecture-android-materials\OsterrigLampLED\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\astar\osterriglampled\di\module\ViewModelModule.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
    AppRepository repository) {
    ^
  symbol:   class AppRepository
  location: class ViewModelModuleD:\Projects\AndroidStudioProjects\clean-architecture-android-materials\OsterrigLampLED\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\astar\osterriglampled\domain\LampsViewModel.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    private final AppRepository mRepository = null;
                  ^
  symbol:   class AppRepository
  location: class LampsViewModelD:\Projects\AndroidStudioProjects\clean-architecture-android-materials\OsterrigLampLED\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\astar\osterriglampled\domain\LampsViewModel.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    AppRepository mRepository) {
    ^
  symbol:   class AppRepository
  location: class LampsViewModelD:\Projects\AndroidStudioProjects\clean-architecture-android-materials\OsterrigLampLED\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\astar\osterriglampled\domain\SingleLampViewModel.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    private final AppRepository mRepository = null;
                  ^
  symbol:   class AppRepository
  location: class SingleLampViewModelD:\Projects\AndroidStudioProjects\clean-architecture-android-materials\OsterrigLampLED\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\astar\osterriglampled\domain\SingleLampViewModel.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    AppRepository mRepository) {
    ^
  symbol:   class AppRepository
  location: class SingleLampViewModelD:\Projects\AndroidStudioProjects\clean-architecture-android-materials\OsterrigLampLED\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\astar\osterriglampled\di\component\DatabaseComponent.java:6: error: com.astar.osterriglampled.di.component.DatabaseComponent is listed as a module, but is not annotated with @Module
```

[image: Screen с ошибкой!]

Вот код **AppRepository**:

```
import com.astar.osterriglampled.repository.database.AppDatabase
import com.astar.osterriglampled.repository.database.entity.Lamp
import io.reactivex.Single
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers

class AppRepository(private val mainDatabase: AppDatabase) {

    fun getAllLamps(): Single<List<Lamp>>? {
        return Single.just(mainDatabase.lampDao().getLamps())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }

    fun getLampByGroups(id: Long): Single<List<Lamp>>  {
        return Single.just(mainDatabase.lampDao().getLampsByGroup(id))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }

    fun getLampById(id: Long): Single<Lamp> {
        return Single.just(mainDatabase.lampDao().getLampById(id))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }

}
```

Код **RepositoryModule**

```
package com.astar.osterriglampled.di.module

import AppRepository
import com.astar.osterriglampled.repository.database.AppDatabase
import dagger.Provides

class RepositoryModule {

    @Provides
    internal fun providesRepository(database: AppDatabase): AppRepository {
        return AppRepository(database)
    }
}
```

И код **RepositoryComponent**

```
@RepositoryScope
@Component(modules = [RepositoryModule::class], dependencies = [DatabaseComponent::class])
interface RepositoryComponent {
    val repository: AppRepository
}
```

Comment: Что бы кто-то вам мог помочь, вам стоит приложить код в котором вы инициализиуете AppRepository

Comment: Очевидно, что вы где-то не прописали зависимость для AppRepository. Но вот где из ошибки не понять

Comment: Складывается ошущение, что такого типа `AppRepository` у автора попросту нет

Comment: Изменил публикацию, добавил код и AppRepository

Comment: от котлина только про синтаксис немного знаю, но глядя на код возникает несколько вопросов: 1. разве `RepositoryModule` без аннотации `@Module` будет работать ? 2. разве `AppRepository` без аннотации `@Inject `конструктора сможет сделать инъекцию `AppDatabase` ? 3. без создания инстанса `RepositoryComponent` билдером разве вообще что-то будет работать ? ответ на все вопросы нет

Comment: Очень похоже на то, что вы, как минимум, забыли аннотацию @Module у класса RepositoryModule.